# To win by a lot

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, phrase-requests, sentence

*The Football players were magnanimous enough to compliment their opponents, even though they won _______.*

Is there a word or phrase that falls along the lines of "windfall", or shows that the Football players scored a decisive victory over their opponents?

Comment: *Convincingly, decisively,* perhaps? I don't see how a windfall (an unexpected good fortune, generally a large sum of money which arrives without any effort) is really relevant here.

Comment: ***by a landslide***.

Comment: **by a huge margin**

Comment: **in a blowout.**

Answer (score 3):

(I was gonna comment this, but I feel it answers the question)
Personally I would use:

"They won by a landslide"

or

"They won massively"

As is alluded to in the comments on my answer, to win by a landslide is usually used in an electorial context. For example: when one politician wins an election with more than 75% of the votes. They won by a landslide.

Comment: Upvoted, Cas! Although you may want to include the [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/landslide) of landslide to support your answer, which may attract more +1s. Might be worth mentioning that the term originated in politics but is now used to refer to basically any decisive victory in a competition.

Comment: I haven't down-voted this, b/c I don't do that, but this is not a very good answer. "Landslide" almost always refers to an electoral victory. I'm not saying it's never used in sports, but, actually, I was an ESPN editor for ten years, and I don't recall ever seeing this expression used for a football game, or any other athletic contest. At best, it is not commonly said.

Answer (score 2):

"walking away." From UPI: "Hield 'struggled' to score 18 points in that game, and yet Oklahoma won walking away."

Also, they won in a rout. From Wikipedia: "The Lions scored two touchdowns in each quarter and won in a rout, 59–14."

A laugher: From the Sports Fan Journal: "Then they won a laugher of a Game Two by the score of 9-0"

Comment: +1 for "won in a rout," and it leads to a nice single-word verb for saying "to defeat decisively."

Answer (score 2):

The word that came to my mind was ***handily***, synonymous with ***easily***, and strongly related to ***effortlessly***.

> ... even though they won ***handily***.

Similarly, ***with ease***.

Answer (score 2):

*The football players were magnanimous enough to compliment their opponents, even though they **won hands down**.*

> win hands down
>
> *Slang.* To win easily
>
> Also, ***in a breeze***; ***in a walk***. Easily, without effort, as in *They won in a breeze, 10-0,* or *The top players get through the first rounds of the tournament in a walk.*
>
> All of these expressions originated in sports. *Hands down*, dating from the mid-1800s, comes from horse racing, where jockeys drop their hands downward and relax their hold when they are sure to win. *In a breeze*, first recorded in a baseball magazine in 1910, alludes to the rapid and easy passage of moving air; *in a walk*, also from baseball, alludes to taking a base on balls, that is, reaching first base without having hit a pitched ball because of the pitcher's mistakes.
>
> [The Dictionary of American Slang](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/win-hands-down)

*The football players were magnanimous enough to compliment their opponents, even though they **beat the pants off them***.

> beat the pants off
>
> Also, ***beat hollow***. Win decisively over someone, outdo. For example, *When it comes to the Patriots' Day parade, Lexington beats the pants off the neighboring towns*, or *This beer beats the other brands hollow.* Both phrases use *beat* in the sense of "surpass." *Pants off* has served as an intensifier since about 1930; the variant dates from about 1775.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+the+pants+off)

*The football players were magnanimous enough to compliment their opponents, even though they **gave them a licking/sound thrashing**.*

> thrashing; *also* [licking](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/licking)
>
> A severe beating
>
> [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thrashing)

Answer (score 0):

Two words come to mind...

trounce
  (traʊns)

v.t.  trounced, trounc•ing. 
1.  to beat severely; thrash. 
2.  to defeat decisively.

i.e. Team A trounced team B with a convincing 10 nil win

OR

dominate
v.intr.
1.  To have or exert strong authority or mastery.
2.  To be situated in or occupy a position that is more elevated or decidedly superior to others.

i.e. Team A dominated team B with a convincing 10 nil win

Comment: To add to this, "destroyed", "annihilated", and "slaughtered" are also useable, though probably not in the context of a team that's also humble and magnanimous.